# How to enable win7 to hibernate on multi-boot environment?

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, hibernate

I run a HP DV6000 multi-boot environment with MacOSX, Ubuntu and Windows 7.

In Windows 7 I cannot hibernate. After a long research, I've found that my Windows 7 partition must be set as active to hibernate to work.

My question is: is there a way to enable hibernate on my system without messing up with my boot loader?  As far as I know (maybe I am wrong), if I set the Windows partition as active my bootloader will get broken and I'll will have to rebuild it, just to make the Windows 7 partition inactive again. I'd rather not ;)